# Phusion, Passenger and Old Node.js issue

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js server using Nginx and Passenger but having the following issue:

Watching the log I can see that Passenger starts the nodeserver but on the client side I've got no answer.

By the way I've followed the instructions on here: [Passenger/Node.js tutorial](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger%3a-Node.js-tutorial) 
which is simple enough to understand.

The program versions that I'm using are these:
nginx v1.4.5
nodejs v0.8.15
passenger v4.0.37
OS ubuntu 12.04

After some tests I've tried to deploy the example server found on [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/) even with that I got the same situation that had with the first server. So I tried to do the same test but this time using Node.js v0.10.26 and it worked just fine, equals as the v0.8.15 passenger runs the server but this time on the client side I got response from server.

Is that issue normal?
Is there a way to deploy my server with the last version of passenger even with an old nodejs version?(because the server cannot run on last Node.js version, for that reason I'm using v0.8.15).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phusion Passenger relies heavily on streams2, so it doesn't work on Node.js 0.8.